# SSL Configuration on Tomcat Network Solutions

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have received 3 .crt from Network Solutions.
AddTrustExternalCARoot
NetworkSolutionsDVServerCA
domain.crt

I have tried followed the instructions given  in link below
http://www.networksolutions.com/support/installation-of-an-ev-ssl-certificate-for-tomcat-apache/

I am getting following error in the browser

Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8443. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)